# Ошибка в laravel "Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist"

Tags: laravel

Я решил сделать свой LoginController, но выходит следующая ошибка:"Target class `[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist` Не пойму почему. Буду рад любой помощи.
КОД КОНТРОЛЛЕРА:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Обработка попыток аутентификации.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` - тут не верно) + extends Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Должно быть `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;`